# How to fetch custom header from HTTP response in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, http, odata, sapui5

I am performing a put operation and it is working great in rest client in response i get pgi header as shown in below image.

[click here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA6mz.jpg)

Now, I try to get the same from sapui5 odatamodel using update method.
Following is my code.

```
oModel.update("/performpgi(Srno='241')", {"Srno":"241"}, null,                                
  function(oData, oResponse) {
     console.log(oResponse.headers.pgi) //undefined
  }, function(err) {});
```

In the response headers I didn't find any pgi Variable.

Can any help me out with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the console.log output anything at all?

Comment: it gives undefined

Comment: How about inspecting oResponse in F12. Is that undefined too?

Comment: yes , it is not showing any pgi variable in headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fnFunction = function(oEvent){
//oEvent has your complete response, headers and so on
//So you can do whatever you want to do.
//please note that this is called on failure so just handle based on response code
};

oModel.attachRequestCompleted(oData?, fnFunction, oListener?);
```

Comment: I tried oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(event){ console.log(event)}), but it is not getting fired.

Comment: Sorry Ashutosh, No updates. As per documentation this has to work :| If you have jsfiddle/jsbin. I could debug. 
Workaround would be to include is the response body itself..

Comment: I cannot use the service outside the environment. It works only in intranet. Give me your skype id I can explain you.